# Is there a command line way to install Telegram?

Tags: apt, telegram

I have tried this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/telegram
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install telegram
```

But no gain it provides an older version of Telegram. So I thought to ask a new question on how to install the latest version of Telegram in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @CelticWarrior It did not solved my problem . If you can provide a command line way , you are most welcome .

Comment: What didn't? The answer gives the links for downloading the installer (.deb) of the latest version (1.0.29). The PPA, by the way, provides 1.0.27 and will soon be updated. What is your problem exactly? Please edit and update if you need to add info, do not keep it in comments that can be deleted for any number of reasons.